# PHP won't send designated variables to my database, but does send data to the DB when i manually fill it in

Tags: php, mysql, location, coordinates

below is my code. it calculates the coordinates of the user, and is supposed to send it to my DB. the calculation takes some time so i set the redirect timer to 9 seconds. the calculations finish and my coordinates are shown, but still nothing is added to my DB. when i change the bound value of 5 and 6. it does work.

```php
<?php
    $lat='
    <script>
        var lat;
        var lng;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        function showPosition(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            document.writeln(lat);
        }
    </script>';

    $lng='
    <script>
        var lat;
        var lng;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        function showPosition(position) {
          lng = position.coords.longitude;
          document.writeln(lng);
        }
    </script>';

    $addinfo = strip_tags($_POST["detailthing"]);
    $titel   = strip_tags($_POST["titel"]);
    $type    = $_POST["welke"];

    session_start();
    include("opendb.php");
    echo $lat;
    echo $lng;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO requests (type, user_id, addinfo, title, lat, lng) VALUES ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )');
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $_SESSION["user_id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(3, $addinfo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(4, $titel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(5, $lat, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(6, $lng, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    header("refresh: 9;url=https://agile130.science.uva.nl/#linkposts");
?>
```

Comment: Where do you get the post parameters from?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you don't actually have to use `bindValue` for PDO. You could just pass an array of values in the correct order to `execute()`.

Comment: @Shadow from another file ( index.php)

Comment: `$lng='<script>....` - do you expect these PHP variables to contain values that the scripts calculate?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes. the script retrieves the user location, which is stored in the php variable

Comment: That's not how web works. You need to learn about the [difference in client and server side programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). You'll need AJAX to achieve what you want.

Comment: `the script retrieves the user location`...sure, but when the query is executed, the Javascript scripts haven't been executed yet! It will be trying to insert the `<script>var lat;...` etc string into your database! Javascript is executed on the browser, whereas PHP is executed on the server. When a request is made, nothing is delivered to the browser until the PHP has finished executing. And when the browser receives the output from the PHP, it can display it...but then nothing from there is delivered back to the server until another HTTP request is made.

Comment: All you've done here is create some PHP string variables, which happen to contain some Javascript code. Then you try to insert those strings into your database. I'm guessing you're probably trying to insert them into integer fields, which will cause the query to fail (but if you enabled PDO and PHP error handling, you'd know the error for sure). You need to echo the scripts to the page, let them execute, and then send a request back to the server containing the result...only then, on that second request, can you execute your SQL query.

Comment: @ADyson Actually, they are echoed, there are two lines `echo $lat;` and `echo $lng;`, right before the query. The rest stands, though.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the response, turns out this is more complicated than i initially thought.

Comment: @El_Vanja thanks for the link!

Comment: @El_Vanja just spotted that before you and edited the comment :-)